# classNotFoundException DispatcherServlet Exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am trying to learn spring 3 MVC.
I downloaded sample project from the below link
http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-mvc-hello-world/

I am getting classNotFoundException
I am using eclipse IDE, Toamcat 7.0. I attached my project here.
http://www.sendspace.com/file/4twdy6

Could someone please help me what I am missing.

As per the comments: Exception log is below:

```
    Sep 06, 2013 6:33:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;.
        Sep 06, 2013 6:33:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVC' did not find a matching property.
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
        Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 997 ms
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet springDispatcher as unavailable
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringMVC threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 06, 2013 6:33:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 601 ms
```

Thanks

Comment: It's better to put the exception output than uploading the whole project to some sharing web service

Comment: And now you need to format it properly :)